# iterating through pointer arrays and displaying

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

ii'm having some issues understanding pointer arrays, see the following simplified code

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//holds two different datatypes
template <typename A, typename B>
class data {
public:
    A dataA;
    B dataB;
    data(){}
    data* add(A dataA, B dataB){
        this->dataA = dataA;
        this->dataB = dataB;
        return this;
    }
};
//stores an array of the data
template <typename  A, typename B>
class container {
    data<A, B> **dataArray;
    int ammount;
public:
    typedef data<A, B> * iterator;
    container(){
        //create dynamic array of pointers
        dataArray = new data<A, B>*[5];
        ammount = 0;
    }
    ~container(){
        for (int i = 0; i <= ammount; i++)
        {
            delete dataArray[i];
        }
    }

    void add(A dataA, B dataB){
        data<A, B> *newItem;
        if (ammount <= 5){
            newItem = new data<A, B>();
            dataArray[ammount] = newItem->add(dataA, dataB);
            ammount++;
        }
    }
    //basic iterators
    iterator begin(){
        return *dataArray;
    }
    iterator end(){
        return dataArray[5];
    }
};

void main(){
    string somestuff[] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
    container<string, int> foo;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        foo.add(somestuff[i], i);
    }
    container<string, int>::iterator it = foo.begin();
    // why cant i just iterate through each item in the array
    for (it; it < foo.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << "Data A : " << it->dataA << " Data B : " << it->dataB << "\n";
    }

}
```

the issue is in main, I cant move through the array when displaying. Am I looking at this problem all wrong ?

ps I am aware STL containers would be better here but I need to understand this specific scenario, i.e. a dynamic array(not using vector) of pointers to objects

**edit 
i have added a few output statements to show what I am trying to achieve

output is

```
Adding data
Added Data at address : 00779218
Added Data at address : 00779458
Added Data at address : 007794B8
Added Data at address : 00779560
Added Data at address : 00779730
Printing data
The address of 'it' is now: 00779218
Data A : one Data B : 0
incerementing from map.begin
The address of 'it' is now: 00779238
Data A :  Data B : 469784212
incerementing from map.begin
The address of 'it' is now: 00779258
Data A : X Data B : -33686019
incerementing from map.begin
The address of 'it' is now: 00779278
```

when i am doing this

```
for (it; it < foo.end(); it++){
        cout << "The address of 'it' is now: "<<it<<"\n";
        cout << "Data A : " << it->dataA << " Data B : " << it->dataB << "\n";
        cout << "incerementing from map.begin\n";

    }
```

I need the 'it' variable top point at the next item in the dataArray, it is incrementing just not properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this program:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//holds two different datatypes
template <typename A, typename B>
class data {
  public:
    A dataA;
    B dataB;
    data* _next;
    data(){_next = NULL;}
    data* add(A dataA, B dataB){
      this->dataA = dataA;
      this->dataB = dataB;
      return this;
    }


    bool operator<(data& rhs)
    {
      if (this->dataB ==rhs.dataB);
      return true;
      return (this->dataB <rhs.dataB);
    }

    data* operator++()
    {
      if(this == NULL)
        return NULL;
      return _next;
    }
};
//stores an array of the data
template <typename  A, typename B>
class container {
  data<A, B> **dataArray;
  int ammount;
  public:
  typedef data<A, B> * iterator;
  container(){
    //create dynamic array of pointers
    dataArray = new data<A, B>*[5];
    ammount = 0;
  }
  ~container(){
    for (int i = 0; i < ammount; i++)
    {
      delete dataArray[i];
    }
  }

  void add(A dataA, B dataB){
    data<A, B> *newItem;
    if (ammount <= 5){
      newItem = new data<A, B>();
      dataArray[ammount] = newItem->add(dataA, dataB);
      if(ammount != 0)
      { 
        dataArray[ammount -1]->_next = dataArray[ammount];
      }
      ammount++;
    }
  }
  //basic iterators
  iterator begin(){
    return *dataArray;
  }
  iterator end(){
    return dataArray[4];
  }


};

int main(){
  string somestuff[] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
  container<string, int> foo;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    foo.add(somestuff[i], i);
  }
  container<string, int>::iterator it = foo.begin();
  // why cant i just iterate through each item in the array
  for (it; *it < *foo.end(); it =++ *it)
  {
    if(it != NULL)
    cout << "Data A : " << it->dataA << " Data B : " << it->dataB << "\n";
    else
      return  0;
  }
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I can only access the first item, anything after that is undefined

Comment: Ah ok could you give me any pointers (bad pun) on how to implement the ++ operator for this

Comment: Hi thanks so much for your help, however the operators are'aren't being used, no breakpoints can be triggered and in the display loop the it variable isn't incrementing to the next value in the array, see update in question for output

Comment: Thanks that works, almost like a linked list implementation but it fixed my problem, one more question ...the reason I was doing it like this was because I though  an iterator class would be overkill for an array. In your view would there be any benefit to having a separate iterator class for this ?

Comment: I have edited once again now all 5 values are being printed. Since your objective I think is to play around dynamic allocation yourself and not use STL, you could try and implement a friend iterator class. Depends on what you are aiming for.